# How to make null last when sorting

Tags: sql

I have the following SQL-question.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   forum_l.entries 
       LEFT JOIN forum_h.user 
              ON forum_l.entries.uid = forum_h.user.userid 
ORDER  BY username 
LIMIT  $offSetRows, $nrOfrows;
```

I get all values I want including NULL in left table. But I want to order by username. Now I get NULL or 0 first. How can I get empty values last?

Comment: `ORDER BY CASE WHEN forum_h.user.userid IS NOT NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, username`

Comment: What do you mean "NULL or 0 first"?  `username` is presumably a string.  Why would you care if a string is `'0'` as opposed to other values?

Comment: Well, username is a string but userid is not. If userid is not 0 there is a username otherwise not. I may be confused here.

Comment: `order by username nulls first` would be standard SQL. Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `CASE` in the `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   forum_l.entries 
       LEFT JOIN forum_h.user 
              ON forum_l.entries.uid = forum_h.user.userid 
ORDER  BY CASE WHEN username IS NULL OR username = '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ASC,
         username ASC
LIMIT  $offSetRows, $nrOfrows;
```

I think "NULL or 0" meant `NULL` or username with length = 0.

Comment: Your first answer seem to work fine! Thanks! How do I mark as answered and give you points?

Comment: @LarsPersson: once you have enough reputation you can upvote answers (and questions), Apart form that you should accept the best answer by clicking the green check mark beside the answer. You can read about it [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use a database that supports the ANSI standard `NULLS FIRST` syntax in `ORDER BY` clauses.  Barring that, you can do it explicitly, using a conditional expression:

```
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN username IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 2 END),
         username
```

In MySQL, you can simplify this to:

```
ORDER BY (username IS NULL) DESC, username
```

I'm not sure what you mean by "0" first, because `username` is presumably a string.  However, you can use the same approach to put any values first or last.